# Possible to send HTML Emails in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible to send HTML emails from WP7? I might have overlooked it but it doesn't appear that there is a parameter in the EmailComposeTask for specifying this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the device is capable of receiving and displaying HTML emails, the `EmailComposeTask` does not provide an API to enable you to send HTML emails. If this is a requirement of your application (and I'd caution you on using up too much user bandwidth for larger volumes of data), then you will need to access a web service that provides access to a mail server for you.

Comment: yeah I wasn't sending anything extraneous, but I can see how this could be abused. Perhaps Microsoft could implement a limit and give developers the option in the future. Thanks for the quick response anyway.