# Is there any way to send HTML formatted mails from code directly on a Windows Phone 7 device?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have an app where the user can send some data via email, sort of like a report. This works fine but I would like some more formatting. The best thing would be if it was possible to create some HTML code and add it to the mail. Is this possible?

Comment: Duplicate: Possible to send HTML emails in WP7? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492804/possible-to-send-html-emails-in-wp7

Comment: Sorry, searched and searched but obviously not that good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Windows Phone 7 you can only start the [EmailComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394003%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) which does not have any way to include HTML based email. You will need to send this from a web service, which in all honesty is probably the better option anyway, as you'll be able to log who sent what when, etc.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. And I can't attach a simple txt-file?

Comment: Again, to include an attachment, a web service is the way to go.