# How can I send hyperlink to a person via Email?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to send a URL through mail embedded with a hyperlink but it does not seem to work in anyway.  Is there any solution where I send the hyperlink with the help of [EmailTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh394003(v=vs.105).aspx)?

Comment: I do not know exactly this class, but usually, you can set, if the body of email is send as text or html. The solution is to choose html and then you can send whatever html you want, including hyperlink.

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492804/possible-to-send-html-emails-in-wp7  (though there exist 3rd party libraries that will do it for you)